# Remove parameters from URL and paste finished string to address bar

Tags: php

I am new to php and I would appreciate any help you could offer. I wish to remove the parameters from a URL. I can remove them using the code below but my question is how can i parse the result into the address bar. I don't want to reload the page via `header("Location: index.php")` because i lose the use of the parsed variable. I have looked at other questions but they do not tell you how to parse to finished string into the address bar. Here is my code below.

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST["add"])
{
    $message = "Item has been added";
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = strtok($url, '?');
}
?>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $message;
?>
<a href="?add=item">Click Add</a>
```

Comment: If you "change the address bar", you reload the page. That's what "changing the address bar" means. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Once, you are in the `page.php?id232423` nothing you do to remove the params, will change how the page behaves.

Comment: At the moment if a user clicks the link the address bar has `index.php?add=item` I would like to remove the `?add=item` but still use the parameter

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The most likely solution is that you *do* redirect via `header` after you're done using the parameter.

Comment: You can use JS to alter the URL with the new HTML5 pushState API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your question right, you want to load only the page url without the parameters while still doing the operation you requested.

There are 2 ways to do that.

-- Use a `form` with method post.

```
<form method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='item' value='item' />
    <input type='submit' name='add' value='Add Item' />
</form>
```

Then, in PHP, you can get the value of the added item from the POST variable like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //do something with $_POST['item']
}
```

-- Send the value to a session variable and reload the page

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['added']) && isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $_SESSION['added'] = $_GET['add'];
    header('location: '.strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?'));
}
```

Comment: I should warn you that using POST with a hidden input can open your page for attacks. Be sure to sanitize the param if you are going to send it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove them from the URL if you want to use them from it. If you don't want to have stuff like that in the URL then try to pass the arguments in POST or preferably store the current "action" in session, to hide it completely from the user.

For example instead of putting the action in the URL you can just do

```
$_SESSION['action'] = add-item
```

and then handle the session parameter on the same page. So if

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['action'])){//do nothing}
```

else handle the action in some way you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking for the [Post/Redirect/Get design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

You cannot "change the address bar"*. The address bar shows the URL the browser is currently on and the URL the browser is on influences what the server does/did to produce the response.

<sub>* Notwithstanding the HTML5 Javascript history API.</sub>